# The type arguments for method System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to follow the demo from this [link](http://www.timdavis.com.au/code/jquery-grid-with-asp-net-mvc/) to add a jqGrid to an MVC app.

I have a table named Companies that I'm trying to display in a grid. A Company simply contains an ID and a Name.

I'm running into an error in my controller function:

```
public JsonResult DynamicGridData(string sortIndex, string sortOrder, int page, int rows)
{
    int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
    int pageSize = rows;

    var companies = companiesRepository.Companies.OrderBy(sortIndex + " " + sortOrder).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    //Error here

    ...
}
```

I'm getting an error on the line that is calling OrderBy():

> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I really have no idea what the error means, and I haven't been able to find an explanation. I'm not sure what is causing this error on a simple OrderBy function.

Comment: Just add `using System.Linq.Dynamic;` or `using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;` for core projects.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You cannot `OrderBy` a string; you need to pass a lambda expression or delegate.

You need to use [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx), as mentioned in the tutorial.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I can do that here?

Comment: You simply need to include the library and namespace.

Comment: I am trying to use Dynamic LINQ. The problem is that I don't know the property I'm sorting on. I'm passing it in as a string. How can I convert the string into a lambda expression?

Comment: If you use Dynamic LINQ, you can pass a string.  Otherwise, you'll need to build an expression tree.

Comment: I can't pass a string, my OrderBy() function doesn't take a string as a parameter. It is expecting System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Company,TKey>>

Comment: @Steven: Did you add the `using` statement for Dynamic LINQ?

Comment: Add "using System.Linq.Dynamic" int the top of the file.

Answer (score 33):

The specific answer to this question is you need to add

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
```

and you need to add a reference to `Dynamic.DLL` in your project.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. No idea why this isn't accepted as answer.

Comment: In my case its using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core; and not using System.Linq.Dynamic. Note the core

Comment: using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core; is indeed necessary, at least in .net 5.0

Answer (score 11):

I know this is a school-boy error from my part, but I got this same error "CS0411   The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.OrderBy(IEnumerable, Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.".

It turns out the "property" I was sorting on, was actually a function, and I had omitted the "()". It took me AGES to find!

In my code exerpt:

```
return _numbers.Values.OrderBy(x => x.TotalScore);
```

should have been

```
return _numbers.Values.OrderBy(x => x.TotalScore());
```

Just thought I would mention it......

Comment: Might not be the right place, but you saved my life.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. I assumed something was a property and not a function...

Answer (score 8):

If you consulted the documentation for the method you are calling ([Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx)), you would know that the parameter is a `Func<TSource, TKey>` and not a string.

> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

The compiler attempted to figure out how the string parameter was actually a Func and then decided that it couldn't determine what TSource is and what TKey is.  It's asking you to help out by specifying those types in the call, like this:

```
companiesRepository.Companies.OrderBy<Company, int>(sortIndex + " " + sortOrder)
```

If you do that, then the compiler will instead tell you that string isn't a correct parameter, because now it has enough information to know that.

Comment: That won't compile either.  It takes a delegate, not a string.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.  I'm not trying to teach him how to do what he's attempting, I'm just trying to explain what the compiler is saying.

Answer (score 3):

If you are referencing `System.Linq.Dynamic`, don't forget to add `using System.Linq.Dynamic;`
If you are referencing `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`, don't forget to add `using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;`

Answer (score 2):

1. Add the reference `System.Linq.Dynamic.dll` to your project.
2. Then, add the namespace: `using System.Linq.Dynamic;`

Comment: does not exist in .net core or ef core. any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

For .Net Core project, need to add a reference of System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;

Comment: Repeats [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58789889/861716) (for the Core part). Please only post an answer if it adds something significant.